# only every second element is iterated

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-animations

I have list of element to animate through CSS3, like so:

```
.anim-slide-left {
    animation: anim-slide-left 0.8s ease forwards;
    -webkit-animation: anim-slide-left 0.8s ease forwards;

}
@-webkit-keyframes anim-slide-left {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(-500px);
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-500px);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateX(0);
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

/* there are more, but very similar */
```

When the page is loaded js should animate only visible elements with special class 'animate':

```
$(function() {

    var $window = $(window);
    var $toAnimate = $('.animate');
    animate();

        // check if element is on the viewport
    function isElementVisible(elementToBeChecked)
    {
        var TopView = $(window).scrollTop();
        var BotView = TopView + $(window).height();
        var TopElement = elementToBeChecked.offset().top;
        return ((TopElement <= BotView) && (TopElement >= TopView));
    }
        // add css animation class
    function animate()
    {
        $toAnimate.each(function(i, el)
        {
            var $el = $toAnimate.eq(i);

            if ($el.length && isElementVisible($el))
            {
                    // remove already visible elements
                $toAnimate.splice(i, 1);

                    // setting up animation effect
                $el.addClass( $el.data('effect') );

                $el.removeClass('animate');
            } 
        });
    }
});
```

Now here is the problem. Only every second element is checked as visible, like so:

[image]

But it should be like this:

[image]

The rest of elements are animated only when the page is scrolled down, with:

```
$window.scroll( function()
{
    animate();
});
```

How to iterate through every element in this scenario ?

EDIT:

Taking note of @T.J. Crowder comments I modified animate function with filter function suggested by @charlietfl:

```
$('.animate').filter( function( idx ) {
    if( isElementVisible($(this)) )
    {
        $(this).addClass( $(this).data('effect') );
        $(this).removeClass('animate');
    }
});
```

It works just fine :) Thank you guys.

Comment: Well, things like that are likely to happen when you remove entries from the set you're looping through (`$toAnimate`).

Comment: Also note that `splice` is not an official jQuery method. It is undocumented and could disappear at any time. (jQuery objects are not arrays; they are just *array-like*.)

Comment: **And** as far as I'm aware, jQuery makes [no guarantees](http://api.jquery.com/each/) about what `each` will do if you add or remove entries in the set you're iterating (unlike JavaScript's `forEach`).

Comment: you probably want `filter()` instead of using `each()` and `splice()`. `splice()` is destructive to original collection whereas `filter()` is not

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thank you for your comments, you are absolutely right, so I believe that @charlietfl answer is the best with `filter` function.

Answer (score 5):

Several problems there:

1. You're modifying the set (`$toAnimate`) that you're iterating, and you're retrieving items from that set with an ever-increasing index. So naturally, if you remove one, from that point forward your indexes are going to be off.
2. `splice` is not an official jQuery method. It is undocumented and could disappear at any time. (jQuery objects are not arrays; they are just *array-like*.)
3. As far as I'm aware, jQuery makes [no guarantees](http://api.jquery.com/each/) about what `each` will do if you add or remove entries in the set you're iterating (unlike JavaScript's `forEach`).

Because you have `splice` and the iteration guarantee from `forEach`, you could make `$toAnimate` an actual array by using [`.get`](http://api.jquery.com/get):

```
var $toAnimate = $('.animate').get();
// ---------------------------^^^^^^
```

...and then:

```
function animate()
{
    $toAnimate.forEach(function(el)
    {
        var $el = $(el);
        if (isElementVisible($el))
        {
            // remove already visible elements
            $toAnimate.splice(i, 1);

            // setting up animation effect
            if( $el.data('effect') == 'anim-bar' ) animateBar($el);
            else $el.addClass( $el.data('effect') );

            $el.removeClass('animate');
        } 
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are removing items from the array that you are iterating, so the next item will take the place of the current. When you move on to the next item, that will skip one item.

If you loop through the array from the end, removing the items doesn't affect the items later in the loop:

```
function animate()
{
    for (var i = $toAnimate.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        var $el = $toAnimate.eq(i);

        if ($el.length && isElementVisible($el))
        {
                // remove already visible elements
            $toAnimate.splice(i, 1);

                // setting up animation effect
            if( $el.data('effect') == 'anim-bar' ) animateBar($el);
            else $el.addClass( $el.data('effect') );

            $el.removeClass('animate');
        } 
    });
}
```

Comment: That works, thank you, but I have to take notice of others comments as well, like jquery compatibility.